# asp.net mvc 4: RenderBody() is writing out Model name to the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i am working/tweaking the default install of asp.net mvc 4 .. added some views ..

and when i try to pass a model to my view, that model (name and namespace) gets written out to page.

```
@Model Blah.Web.UI.Models.DirectoryModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Directory";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

when i view my page, i see

> Blah.Web.UI.Models.DirectoryModel Blah.Web.UI.Models.DirectoryModel

written out twice at the top of the page..

my controller just initializes the model and passes it inside the view..

also i noticed that this happens within @RenderBody() called form _layout.. so i am assuming it is done somewhere in my view..

even if i comment out all code on my view (accept the declaration above) i still see this string written out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
@Model Blah.Web.UI.Models.DirectoryModel
```

to

```
@model Blah.Web.UI.Models.DirectoryModel
```

The `@model` directive with lower case `m` tells razor what is the type of the model.

On the other hand `@Model` with upper case `M` just calls `ToString` on the view's `Model` property and writes the string in the response.

That is why

```
 @Model Blah.Web.UI.Models.DirectoryModel
```

Ouptuts: `Blah.Web.UI.Models.DirectoryModel Blah.Web.UI.Models.DirectoryModel`

First it writes the the `ToString` of the `Model` and the rest of the line `Blah.Web.UI.Models.DirectoryModel` as plain text.

Comment: ah thanks! that makes sense.. however the declaration still worked, because i was still able to use that model later.. so is that declaration optional just for the intelisese etc ?

Comment: the `@model` is not just for intelisense: behind the scenes mvc creates a class of `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<T>` for each view. And with the `@model` you tell mvc what should be the type parameter `T`. If you don't use `@model` then it will use `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic>`